# Why is index.html being treated as JSON? Unexpected token < at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am trying to use Qunit to make unit tests for this html. The error I'm getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. It's pointing to the "<" in `<!DOCTYPE html>` Clearly this isn't JSON, but it thinks it is, but I'm not sure why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
          <title>Pinpoint Test</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.css">

          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>  
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jshamcrest.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="integration.js"></script>  
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jsmockito-1.0.4.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

          <script src="pinpoint.js"></script>
          <script src="pinpointTest.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="qunit"></div>
          <div id="qunit-fixture">
          //a lot more html
    </body>
    </html
```

It says `Source: at window.onerror (https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.js:322:11)`

qunit-2.0.0.js:

```
    // Cover uncaught exceptions
    // Returning true will suppress the default browser handler,
    // returning false will let it run.
    window.onerror = function( error, filePath, linerNr ) {
        var ret = false;
        if ( onErrorFnPrev ) {
            ret = onErrorFnPrev( error, filePath, linerNr );
        }

        // Treat return value as window.onerror itself does,
        // Only do our handling if not suppressed.
        if ( ret !== true ) {
            if ( QUnit.config.current ) {


        if ( QUnit.config.current.ignoreGlobalErrors ) {
                    return true;
                }
                QUnit.pushFailure( error, filePath + ":" + linerNr );
            } else {
//322               QUnit.test( "global failure", extend( function() {
                    QUnit.pushFailure( error, filePath + ":" + linerNr );
                }, { validTest: true } ) );
            }
            return false;
        }

        return ret;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that missing `>` at the end of your html file is just a typo in this example? I think you might need to put all these `<script>` tags at the end of your `<body>` instead of in the `<head>`... QUnit wants that `<div id="qunit"></div>` tag to put its UI in, and as it is, your tests are trying to run before the HTML ever loads. Give that a try, but if it doesn't work, can you simplify your test to just a simple `assert.equall(1, 1)` to see if that works? You could also update the question with your actual tests if you want us to look at them.